# How to generate a file with a list of 10 random numbers, sort them and write to a new file

Tags: python

PYTHON. Generate a file numbers.txt filled with a list of 10 random numbers. Read the numbers,
sort them and write to a new file sorted_numbers.txt.
I have this, it only reads. I don't know how to sort it.

````
f= open("numbers.txt","w+")
line=(random.sample(range(100),10))
line2=str(line)
f.write(line2)
#print(line)
f.close()

f=open("numbers.txt", "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
   contents =f.read()
   print(contents)
f.close() ```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. [Sorting How To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open ('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    new_list = sorted([int(i.replace('\n', '')) for i in f.readlines()])

with open ('sorted_numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in new_list:
        f.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

This should work.

it takes the original txt file (`numbers.txt`) and go over the numbers and sort them to a new SORTED list, after that it writes the sorted numbers to a new txt file (`sorted_numbers.txt`).

Edit:

```
import random


# create a list with random 10 numbers in range of (0 - 100)
random_list = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)]

# create a file with those numbers (unsorted!)
with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as file:
    for n in random_list:
        file.write(str(n) + '\n')


# create a new file and add the sorted numbers this time
with open ('numbers.txt', 'r') as read_file:
    # sort the list
    new_list = sorted([int(i.replace('\n', '')) for i in read_file.readlines()])
    with open ('sorted_numbers.txt', 'w') as write_file:
        for j in new_list:
            write_file.write(str(j) + '\n')
```

This code creates all the files.
Its generate 10 random nums and create a file with the numbers, then read this file and sort the numbers and write it to the a new sorted txt file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should convert the numbers from a string form to an int:

```
for i in range(len(contents)):
 contents[i]=int(contents[i])
```

Once you've done that you can just use sort():

```
contents.sort()
```

And you are done.
Hope it works.